# Numpy reduce multiple operations for hashing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, hash, reduce

I'm trying to implement some hashing functions for numpy arrays to easily find these inside a big list of arrays, but almost every hashing function I find needs to make a `reduce` with more than one operation, [for example](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html):

```
def fnv_hash (arr):
    result = FNV_offset_basis
    for v in arr.view(dtype = np.uint8):
        result *= FNV_prime
        result ^= v
    return result
```

It would take two operations to the `result` variable in each loop, which (I think) is not possible using only `reduce` calls in numpy functions (i.e. `numpy.ufunc.reduce`).

I want to avoid basic loops as they do not treat numpy arrays as memory regions (which is slow) and I don't want to use `hashlib` functions. Also, converting a function using `numpy.vectorize` and similar (which is just a for loop as said in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)) does not helps performance.

Unfortunately I cannot use `numba.jit` because, as I'm working with large arrays, I need to run my code in a cluster which doesn't have `numba` installed. The same happens for `xxhash`.

My solution so far is to use a simple hashing function as

```
def my_hash (arr):
    indices = np.arange(arr.shape[0])
    return int((arr * ((1 << (indices * 5)) - indices)).sum())
```

Which is kinda fast (this isn't the actual function code, I made some optimizations in my script but I can assure you the output is the same), but it makes some unwanted collisions.

In short: I want to implement a good hashing function using only numpy operations, as my arrays and my search space are enormous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if its helpful, but one could optimize `my_hash` with `int(arr.dot((1 << (indices * 5)) - indices))`.

Comment: In your `fnv_hash` function you seem to be assuming that your arrays are 1-dimensional, is that always true?

Comment: @exp1orer yes they are

Comment: You might want to consider compiling your own [`gufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html) in C, with signature `(i)->()` that performs those operations. [this file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/umath_tests.c.src) contains some examples of how to do that. I'm afraid I can't advise on how to set up the compilation in the right way

Comment: Can you `pip install --user numba`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use hashlib? And can you give a reproducible example showing 1) how large are the arrays you're working with 2) how many are there 3) how slow is a "naive" approach, and then how fast does it need to be?

Comment: @Eric thanks, with the flag `--user` I could install xxhash (but not numba, as I needed clang as dependency)

Comment: @exp1orer hashlib is for secure cryptographic applications, being slow in these simple cases. I'm actually trying to build an example, but here are some data about my problem:
1) my arrays can assume more than 2 ** 31 elements
2) in the worst case I'm working with 8192 arrays but this number can grow bigger
3) my naive approach takes approx. 1s to run and generates some conflicts in the runtime, which increases considerably the time, as I need to compare the arrays. I want a solution that runs in approx. the same time but with less conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Since your arrays are enormous, but you don't have many of them, did you try hashing just a part of each array? For example, even if `arr` is huge, `hash(tuple(arr[:10e5]))` is ~60ms on my machine and is probably unique enough to distinguish 10k different arrays, depending on how they were generated.

If this won't solve your problem, any additional context you can give on your problem would be helpful. How and when are these arrays generated? Why are you trying to hash them?